# How to edit post meta by post ID in Gutenberg

Tags: block-editor

What is the best practice to do this in Gutenberg/JavaScript:

```
update_post_meta( $page_id, '_custom_post_meta', 'Some data to be saved' );
```

- I need to do this from a sidebar box
- Custom meta is registered, and I can update it for currently edited post
- I need to do it for another post, not the one currently edited

Here is the use case:

```
const UpdateMeta = () => {

    const { editPost } = useDispatch( 'core/editor' );
    const onChange = ( value ) => {
        editPost( { // I am updating currently edited post here, and that's fine
            meta: { _custom_meta : JSON.stringify( value ) },
        } );

        // But, I would like to change some other post meta, selected by thID
    };

    return (
        <FormTokenField
            value={ selectedContinents }
            suggestions={ suggestionsList }
            __experimentalShowHowTo={false}
            onChange={ onChange }
            displayTransform={ prepare }
        />
    );
}


const Component = () => (
    <PluginDocumentSettingPanel
        title={ 'My Sidebar Box' }>
        <UpdateMeta/>
    </PluginDocumentSettingPanel>
);


registerPlugin( 'my-plugin-name', {
    icon: '',
    render: Component,
} );
```

I excluded nonrelevant parts of the code.

**Update:**
I am sharing full code here (code is WIP, please ignore eventual mistakes and deficiencies:

```
const { registerPlugin } = wp.plugins;
const { FormTokenField } = wp.components;
const { PluginDocumentSettingPanel } = wp.editPost;
const { useSelect, useDispatch } = wp.data;
const { useState } = wp.element;
let targetType = '';

const RelatedDifferentTypePosts = () => {

    const postType = wp.data.select( 'core/editor' ).getCurrentPostType();

    switch ( postType ) {
            case 'display':
                targetType = 'event';
                break;
            case 'event':
                targetType = 'display';
                break;
    }

    const postMetaField = `_assigned_${  targetType  }s`;

    const isLoading = useSelect( ( select ) => {
        return select( 'core/data' ).isResolving( 'core', 'getEntityRecords',  [
            'postType', targetType
        ] );
    } );

    const assignedPosts = useSelect(
        ( select ) => select( 'core/editor' ).getEditedPostAttribute( 'meta' )[postMetaField], []
    );

    const targetPostsRaw = useSelect(
        ( select ) => select( 'core' ).getEntityRecords( 'postType', targetType ), []
    );

    let valueTitlePair = [];
    if ( targetPostsRaw ) {
        valueTitlePair = targetPostsRaw.map( ( postItem ) => {
            const tempObj = {};
            tempObj.id = postItem.id;
            tempObj.slug = postItem.slug;
            return tempObj;
        } );
    }

    const slugs = assignedPosts ? Array.from( JSON.parse( assignedPosts ), ( item ) => { return item.slug; } ) : [];
    const [ selectedPosts, setSelectedPosts ] = useState( slugs );

    let suggestionsList;
    if ( targetPostsRaw ) {
        suggestionsList = Array.from( targetPostsRaw, ( postItem ) => {
            return postItem.slug;
        } );
    }

    const { editPost } = useDispatch( 'core/editor' );
    const onChange = ( value ) => {

        /* Prevent entering non existing Events */
        value = value.filter( ( entry ) => suggestionsList.includes( entry ) );

        setSelectedPosts( value );
        value = valueTitlePair.filter( pair => value.includes( pair.slug ) );

        editPost( {
            meta: { [ postMetaField ] : JSON.stringify( value ) },
        } );
    };

    const prepare = ( token ) => {
        return token.replaceAll( '-', ' ' ).replace( /(^\w|\s\w)/g, m => m.toUpperCase() );
    };

    if ( isLoading ) {
        return <h3>Loading...</h3>;
    }

    return (
        <FormTokenField
            value={ selectedPosts }
            suggestions={ suggestionsList }
            __experimentalShowHowTo={false}
            onChange={ onChange }
            displayTransform={ prepare }
        />
    );
};

/**
 * Component
 */
const Component = () => (
    <PluginDocumentSettingPanel
        title={ `Related ${ targetType.charAt( 0 ).toUpperCase() + targetType.slice( 1 ) }s` }>
        <RelatedDifferentTypePosts/>
    </PluginDocumentSettingPanel>
);

registerPlugin( 'related-posts-of-different-type', {
    icon: '',
    render: Component,
} );
```

Comment: where are you doing this from? Is it a blocks edit component? A sidebar panel? Have you registered your meta? And is this for meta on the currently edited post?

Comment: I apologize for lack of information, I thought it would be easier for people to understand and reply if I keep it short. I updated the question.

Comment: are parts still missing? I see references to variables that dont exist and you mention `thID` in a comment but it never appears in the code. What are you trying to do that requires this? Why do you need to modify other posts that aren't the post being edited?

Comment: Only thing still missing are nonrelevant parts of the FormTokenField, like value, suggestions and displayTransform callbacks etc. `value` inside the `onChange` contains IDs of the selected posts in the FormTokenField, and I would like to update those posts meta field with the currently edited post IDs.

Comment: there are definitely parts missing, e.g. `selectedContinents` is used as the value but it's pulled out of thin air, the code shouldn't be able to build, and you didn't add any context for why you need to do this. There's a very high chance that what you're trying to do has a different but much easier method, or eliminates possible solutions by adding constraints. Avoid making the question too generic

Comment: I just added the full code, I hope that helps.

Comment: Oooooh, you're trying to do related posts and want to pick which posts are related to the current post, so you're setting meta on the related posts to point back to this one. This is going to be very slow, if you want to search/filter/query posts by their X Y or Z, then X/Y/Z should be terms in a taxonomy, not post meta. `meta_query` is slow and gets slower as the site gets bigger. Taxonomies and terms don't have this limitation. It would be _significantly_ faster to use a custom taxonomy where the names of the terms are post titles, and the slugs are post IDs, and you'd get your UI for free

Comment: Yeah, I would need to hide the custom taxonomy backend (WP admin) page, and to figure out how to prevent random entries in the FormTokenField which will be automatically provided by custom taxonomy... And to programatically set taxonomy on the related posts when the currently edited post is updated.

Comment: restricting user creation of terms and eliminating the taxonomy management pages are doable and would make good questions on their own, I'd recommend asking them if they haven't been asked already even if you don't pursue that path

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this using the [Backbone JavaScript Client](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/backbone-javascript-client/) provided as part of the `wp-api` core scripts.

You can fetch a post, update its meta, and save it. Make sure you `wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-api' )` or add it to your script's dependencies so the API is available in JavaScript at `wp.api`.

Example:

```
const post = new wp.api.models.Post( { id: 123 } );
post.fetch().done( () => {
    post.setMeta( 'your_meta_field', 'your_meta_string_content' );
    post.save().done( () => {
        // Any actions to perform after the meta has been saved.
    } );
} );
```

The Backbone Client methods don't have great documentation at the time of this writing, but you can inspect them in the source. For example, `setMeta()` is here: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/js/wp-api.js#L543-L553

Be careful since the API returns promises for most methods; it's easy to make a mistake (e.g., trying to set the post meta before the post has been fetched, which won't do anything).

Also note that the REST API has endpoints for each post type, so you will need to use different models for each. For example, `wp.api.models.Post`, `wp.api.models.Page`, `wp.api.models.YourCustomPostTypes`, etc. You may have to save that info along with the ID so you know which endpoint to use.