# get_the_terms inside save_post gives old terms

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms, pre-get-posts, save-post

When I use `get_the_terms` inside `save_post`, I get the old taxonomy terms.
This is something that I would expect from `pre_post_update`, but why does it happens to `save_post` ?

And, more important, how to overcome this?

Code below is simplified, but I actually need to be able to compare old terms with the updated terms, and to create two arrays: $added_terms, and $removed_terms, on the post save/update.

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'get_the_terms', 10, 3 );
public function get_the_terms( $post_id, $post, $update ): void {

        if ( $update ) {

            $ids = [];
            $terms = get_the_terms( $post, 'custom_taxonomy' );

            if ( ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
                foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                    $ids[] = $term->term_id;
                }

                foreach ( $ids as $id ) {
                    $term = get_term_by( 'term_taxonomy_id', $id, "related_{$post_type}" );
                    $added_terms[] = $term->name;
                }
                wp_set_post_terms( 5, $added_terms, 'custom_taxonomy', false );
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `save_post` probably isn't the right hook, think about it this way, if it gave you the new terms you'd still need to open a question asking how to access the old terms rather than the new terms. I'd also avoid naming your class method `get_the_terms`. Finally, you've fallen into a classic mistake of asking how to fix your solution, rather than how to solve your problem. There's is almost certainly a better way to do what you needed to do without doing it this way but you've hidden what you were trying to do so it's not possible to tell

Comment: Also why is `5` hardcoded

Comment: `get_the_terms` is just a temporary name for the stackexchange question, as well as the line with hardcoded id `5`. I am already getting the old terms with `pre_post_update`.

If you had `set_object_terms` on your mind, it won't work because it creates a loop. Using `wp_set_post_terms` inside of it triggers the `set_object_terms` again.

I want to create relations between posts of a different type, as we talked about it here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/409900/148666

Comment: @TahiReu, are you using Gutenberg or the classic editor? Have you tried using the `wp_after_insert_post` hook instead? (just replace `save_post` with `wp_after_insert_post`)

Comment: @SallyCJ Yes this one works ! Thanks! I'm on Gutenberg and I know this is a known issue: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/8032
Please write answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Glad it worked for you! But looking at your loops, why not just add the `$added_terms[] = $term->name;` to the 1st `foreach` ? I know you said "code below is simplified", but are you sure the 2nd loop is necessary? Also, in most cases, `term_taxonomy_id` is the same as `term_id`, but there could still be cases where they are different, so if you want to check by the ID of the term and *not* its term-taxonomy relationship, then you should use `get_term( $id, "related_{$post_type}" )`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue shouldn't happen if you're using the classic editor, however, if you're using the block/Gutenberg editor which uses the REST API, then that issue can be fixed by using the [`wp_after_insert_post` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_after_insert_post/) instead.

Excerpt from https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/11/20/new-action-wp_after_insert_post-in-wordpress-5-6/:

> The new action `wp_after_insert_post` has been added to WordPress 5.6
> to allow theme and plugin developers to run custom code after a post
> and its terms and meta data have been updated.
>
> The `save_post` and related actions have commonly been used for this
> purpose but these hooks can fire *before* terms and meta data are
> updated outside of the classic editor. (For example in the REST API,
> via the block editor, within the Customizer and when an auto-draft is
> created.)

So try using `wp_after_insert_post`:

```php
add_action( 'wp_after_insert_post', 'get_the_terms', 10, 3 );
```